# Lower bound for integral of multiplication

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I need to show that for any function $x:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}^n$ the following holds
$$
\int_{t-T}^t e^{\tau-t} x(\tau)x^\top (\tau)\, d\tau\geq e^{-T}\int_{t-T}^t  x(\tau)x^\top (\tau)\, d\tau
$$
for any $t>T \geq 0$. Is there any way to show this?

I saw this relation in several books, but there was no explanation nor reference for it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$H(t):=e^{-T}\int_{t-T}^t x(\tau)x^\top (\tau) d\tau-\int_{t-T}^t e^{\tau-t}x(\tau)x^\top (\tau) d\tau.$$
The goal is to show that $H(t)$ is a negative definite matrix for all $t\geq T$, i.e., we have $v^\top H(t) v\leq 0$ for all $v\ne 0$. Using the definition of $H(t)$, we have
\begin{align}
v^\top H(t) v&=\int_{t-T}^t (e^{-T}-e^{\tau-t}) (v^\top x(\tau))^2 d\tau\\
&=e^{-t}\int_{t-T}^t (e^{t-T}-e^{\tau}) (v^\top x(\tau))^2 d\tau.
\end{align}
Since $t-T\leq \tau \leq t$, the term $e^{t-T}-e^{\tau}$ is nonpositive. Thus we get $v^\top H(t) v\leq 0$.